# h1 in article before section

Tags: html, semantic-markup, html-heading

I'm not sure if I have my main headline tag and other semantic elements the right way.

Can I use `h1` tag in `article` without additional text before starting `section`?

```html
<main id="main" class="site-main">
 <article itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork" itemscope="itemscope">
  <h1 itemprop="headline">Main Headline</h1>            
   <section itemprop="text">
     <h2>First Section Headline</h2>
     <p>Some text</p>
   </section>
   <section itemprop="text">
     <h2>Second Section Headline</h2>
     <p>Some text</p>
   </section>
   <section itemprop="text">
     <h2>Third Section Headline</h2>
     <p>Some text</p>
   </section>
</article>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `<article>` is a self-contained unit, typically with a heading element so there is nothing preventing you from starting a `<section>` immediately after the heading and [nothing in the specification says otherwise](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sections.html#the-article-element). A heading element is nothing more than the heading of the article in this case.